# How to store the all jpg pictures that I've used in program

Tags: android, drawable

I want to implement an art game android application in Android Studio. But I'm confused about how to store the pictures? There will be 100 or more pictures of art works in game. The idea came to my mind is to minimize the sizes of pictures and adding them in drawable folder. Is there any efficient way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: whats wrong with storing static images in your drawable?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm not sure the efficiency of this method. will that led to any speed or memory problems?

Comment: what is the current size of single image right now?

Comment: original size 97.6 kb. Before you suggested tinyPNG, I used www.reduceimages.com and size became 34.53. After your suggestion, I tried TinyPNG and it converted size into 87.7 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/) to compress your images without loosing ANY quality, I said ANY and I mean it.

and second don't put them in `drawable` because android will increase there sizes when you will generate signed `APK`, instead you should put them in `raw` directory which you can create in `res` directory, like `res/raw`.

Raw directory works same as `drawable` and any files in this directory gets resource Ids just like `drawables` so you can access files in it just like `R.raw.yourimage`.

I work on applications which includes hundreds of images and this is the best approach I have used.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with the space the 100 images takes up you could use a tool like photoshop or similar so compress your images to desired size (publish to web in photoshop).

Other than that I dont see why you shouldnt just save them in a drawable folder.

Comment: I'm just new in android and wanted to be sure. Thank you very much

Comment: If it helped you please mark as a answer or up vote!